# Simple Vuejs Validation code not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to post some js objects to backend only if all items are numbers , here is the code :

```
  var MyApp = new Vue({

        el: '#my_element',
        data: {
            errors: [],
            votes: []
        },

        methods: {
           send_votes: function(){ 
             if(this.validate_votes(this.votes) === true){ 
                 return this.$http.post('/vote', this.votes).then(
                     function (response) {
                          // success message
                     },
                     function (error) {
                          // error message
                      }
                 )
              },
            }

        },

        validate_votes : function (votes) {

                var all_votes_are_number = true;
                $.each(votes, function (item) {
                    if(isNaN(item)){
                        all_votes_are_number = false;
                        MyApp.errors.push('one of votes is not a number');
                    }
                })

                return all_votes_are_number;
         }

   }
```

But My validation to check if one of votes is not a number, does not work and code continue posting and saving data in db! what am I doing wrong ?

**Also** I want to add more validation:  all votes should be unique.

Comment: Are you sure you have checked the documentation for [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)? First parameter of the callback will be the index, not the item itself.

Comment: @MatJ thank you! crazy mistake, let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `validate_votes` function. When using the `$.each` function, the first argument is the index of the item, and the second argument is the item itself. So if votes was an array equal to `['A','B','C']` you would be checking against 0,1,2. Try the below instead:

```
validate_votes : function (votes) {

                var all_votes_are_number = true;
                $.each(votes, function (item, el) {
                    if(isNaN(el)){
                        all_votes_are_number = false;
                        MyApp.errors.push('one of votes is not a number');
                    }
                });

                return all_votes_are_number;
         }
```

Comment: thank you, I get it,  now what about  `Also I want to add more validation: all votes should be unique.`